# How do I define and create a User model for use with Flask-Login?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am attempting to declare a User model in my flask application in order to implement login with the Flask-Login extension. From the flask documentation regarding sql alchemy there is this example which I have used for another model called employees. Here is the code:

```
class Employee(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "employees"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    title = db.Column(db.String(200))
    email = db.Column(db.String(200))
    department = db.Column(db.String(200))

    def __init__(self, name, title, email, department):
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        self.email = email
        self.department = department

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Employee %r>' % self.name
```

This is taken from this page as an exmample [Flask SQL-Alchemy Docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/sqlalchemy/)

I am confused because I am also using alembic to run migrations so by using `alembic revision -m "create user table` I have already created a 'users' table. I created my first model's table (employees) by using the recommendation of the Flask Sql-Alchemy guide as such:

```
from yourapplication.database import init_db
init_db()
```

Here is the confusion. I now need to establish a User model for authentication. How do I do this? Here is my code so far:

```
class User(flask_login.UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.id = username
        self.password = password
```

Notice that I have the User class inherit from `flask_login.Usermixin`. I need this in order for Flask Login to work so now its not instantiated like the Employee model from `db.Model`. But the thing is is that I created an alembic migration to establish my User model. Why am I not able to query the database. What piece of the puzzle am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All `UserMixin` does is provide a common interface that any user model needs to implement to work with Flask-Login.  It does not set up a SQLAlchemy model, it *mixes in* to a model.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        # override UserMixin property which always returns true
        # return the value of the active column instead
        return self.active
```

SQLAlchemy maps Python classes to database tables.  To create these tables if they don't exist, call `db.create_all()`.  If a table already exists, it will not be altered if you changed the model, you need to drop and re-create the table.

Since dropping tables means you lose all your data, it's a better idea to *migrate* the schema and data as you change your model.  Alembic will generate scripts representing these changes.  Instead of using `create_all`, use Alembic to generate a migration creating the table, and then run the migration.

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m 'create user'
alembic upgrade head
```

Now that you have a user model, and have created the table with an initial migration script, you can perform queries on the table and do login related operations on the instances.

```
# create a user
u = User(name='davidism')
db.session.add(u)
db.session.commit()

# query all users
users = User.query.all()

# update a user
u = User.query.filter_by(name='davidism').one()
u.active = False
db.session.commit()

# check if a user is active like Flask-Login
print(u.is_active)
```